# Mutt and Postfix : relay access denied

Tags: email, postfix, mutt

I try to send mail with Mutt through my own mail server. My mail server run Postfix and Dovecot. I configured it by following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-a-mail-server-using-postfix-dovecot-mysql-and-spamassassin). I can send / receive email on my server with Gnome Evolution and many other programs. I would like to use Mutt with this configuration :

```
set realname = "{name}"
set header_cache = ~/.mutt/cache/headers
set certificate_file = ~/.mutt/certificates
set message_cachedir = ~/.mutt/cache/bodies

set spoolfile = imaps://{server address}:993/INBOX
set imap_user = "{address}"
set imap_pass = "{password}"
set imap_passive = no

set smtp_url = "smtp://{server}:587"
set smtp_pass = "{password}"
set from = "{address}"
set use_envelope_from = yes

set ssl_starttls = yes
set ssl_force_tls = yes
```

I use Mutt on my laptop, as a client of my server, so Mutt is not launched from my server.
The problem is, every time I try to send a mail, I have got this error : `SMTP session fail : Relay access denied`

The corresponding logs in /var/log/mail.log are :

```
Jan  7 17:49:58 ns333449 postfix/submission/smtpd[15264]: connect from unknown[{my ip]
Jan  7 17:49:59 ns333449 postfix/submission/smtpd[15264]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from unknown[{my ip}]: 554 5.7.1 <test@yopmail.com>: Relay access denied; from=<{my address}> to=<{destination address}> proto=ESMTP helo=<{my computer}>
Jan  7 17:49:59 ns333449 postfix/submission/smtpd[15264]: lost connection after RCPT from unknown[{my ip}]
Jan  7 17:49:59 ns333449 postfix/submission/smtpd[15264]: disconnect from unknown[{my ip}]
```

I can't understand why. In Gnome Evolution, my mail server parameters are :

- IMAP :

  - Server : {my server address}
  - Port : 993
  - User : {my mail address}
  - SSL on dedicated port
  - Authentication with password
- SMTP :

  - Server : {my server address}
  - Port : 587
  - Server require an authentication
  - STARTTLS after connection
  - Plain authentication
  - User : {my mail address}

I hope I gave you enough information.

**EDIT** : As suggested by tarleb, I wrote `smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1` in `/etc/postfix/main.cf`, this is what I get when I try to send a mail:

```
Jan  8 11:54:16 ns333449 postfix/submission/smtpd[13158]: connect from unknown[{my ip}]
Jan  8 11:54:17 ns333449 postfix/submission/smtpd[13158]: Anonymous TLS connection established from unknown[{my ip}]: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384 (256/256 bits)
Jan  8 11:54:20 ns333449 postfix/submission/smtpd[13158]: warning: unknown[{my ip}]: SASL PLAIN authentication failed:
Jan  8 11:54:21 ns333449 postfix/submission/smtpd[13158]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[{my ip}]
Jan  8 11:54:21 ns333449 postfix/submission/smtpd[13158]: disconnect from unknown[{my ip}]
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like mutt isn't authenticating itself to the server.  I expect the simplest way to solve this to change the `smtp_url` to

```
set smtp_url = "smtp://$imap_user@{server}:587"
```

This tells mutt to login using your `$imap_user`. Change if your SMTP user is different from your IMAP user.  Without this, mutt doesn't know it has to login before it can send mail.

Comment: I tried this, but I get a "SASL Authentication Failed", even if my credentials are correct. This occurs only with Mutt.

Comment: @naccyde Maybe STARTTLS isn't called, which would make authentication impossible.  Could you add `smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1` to your `/etc/postfix/main.cf` and post the log after trying to send?

Comment: I edited the first post with log message from `smtpd_tls_loglevel = 1`

Comment: Huh, interesting. TLS works and authentication is attempted, but fails. Could you try `set smtp_url = "smtp://$imap_user:$imap_pass@{server}:587"`?

Comment: Same problem with `"smtp://$imap_user:$imap_pass@{server}:587"` : SASL Authentication Failed. By the way, if I try to connect to my server through command line with `openssl s_client -connect {server}:587 -starttls smtp` and `EHLO mail` then `AUTH PLAIN` or `AUTH LOGIN`, authentication fail for the password. The password typed is the same as in Gnome Evolution but in base64 :/

Comment: Problem solved, command line authentication works now, but Mutt always fail on "SASL Authentication Failed"

Comment: @naccyde I'm stumped.  The only thing I can think of is to replace the `$imap` variables in `smtp_url` with the actual values.  That shouldn't matter, though. I'll think about it some more, but for now I'm out of ideas. Sorry.

Comment: thank you for your help, I will try to find a solution ;)

Comment: Please, let me know if you find out what went wrong.  I tried to replicate this on a local machine / VM, but everything worked fine with the settings given above (Debian Jessie, Mutt/1.5.23).  Anyway, happy bug hunting ;)